# Can't access to native Gallery app with camera.getPicture

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have the following code, and I'm trying to choose an image from the device gallery, but it only works with the Google Photos app and not with other gallery apps.

```
this.camera.getPicture({    
   sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,     
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,     
   encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,     
   mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,     
   quality: 80,     
   allowEdit: true})
.then(async (imageData) => {    
  console.log(imageData); }, 
(err) => {     
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err)); 
});
```

It returns this error: `"/data/user/0/pt.app.name/cache/.Pic.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"`

I also have my `config.xml` configured as follows:

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- Your platform-specific configuration here -->
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </edit-config>
</platform>
```

**Expected:** I expect to return base64 code or somehow use the `FILE_URI` (I have tried and it returns "/data/user/0/pt.app.name/cache/.Pic.jpg") and convert it to base64.

**Additional Information:**

- ionic-cordova version: 12

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this issue and getting the image selection to work with all gallery apps. Thank you in advance